# How to obtain the element using an outter directive and an innter directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<div outter-directive>
  <label name="innerLabel"></label>
  <input name"inner" type="text" required ng-minlenght=40 placeholder="inner" ng-model="inner.dir" id="inner" etc.. inner-directive></input>
</div>
```

I want to extract the element `input` using the `inner-directive` from the `outter-directive`. The tags are arbitrary.  I want to be able to put the `inner-directive` in any tag and have the `outter-directive` be able to extract that element with the attached `inner-directive` attribute.

I can have the following as well and still work:

```
<div outter-directive>
  <label name="innerLabel"></label>
  <input name"inner" type="text" required ng-minlenght=40 placeholder="inner" ng-model="inner.dir" id="inner" etc..></input>
  <input name"inner2" type="text" required ng-minlenght=40 placeholder="inner2" ng-model="inner.dir2" id="inner" etc..></input>
  <div>
      <input name"inner3" type="text" required ng-minlenght=40 placeholder="inner3" ng-model="inner.dir3" id="inner" etc.. inner-directive></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

I saw this [nested directives](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223006/communication-between-nested-directives) but couldn't quite answer my question.
Any ideas?

Comment: So you just want to get a DOM element `input` from `outer-directive`?

Comment: any DOM element that has the `innder-directive` nested from the `outer-directive`

Comment: Spot a typo, the `ng-minlenght` should be `ng-minlength`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use directive controllers and `require:` for the communication between parent and children directives.

```
.directive('outerDirective', function () {
  return {
    controller: function () {
      this.elements = [];

      this.addElement = function (element) {
        this.elements.push(element);
      };
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, outerCtrl) {
      console.log(outerCtrl.elements); // this should contains children elements already.
    }
  };
})   

.directive('innerDirective', function () {
  return {
    require: '^outerDirective', // require a controller of parent directive named 'outerDirective'
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, outerCtrl) {
      outerCtrl.addElement(element[0]); // tell the parent controller for an existence.
    }
  };
})
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/F8JZeK7PRBoIHUYaTKtc?p=preview

Comment: I like this method. It can expand out to adding more than one `inner-direcitve` sibling and passing `scope`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal DOM element retrieval methods, like [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll). For example:

```
.directive('outterDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var innerElement = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('[inner-directive]'));
            innerElement.addClass('active');
        }
    };
});
```

In the above example you get inner element and add `active` class to it to illustrate the approach.

You can also use `querySelectorAll` if you want to select all `innerDirective` elements nested inside of `outerDirective`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5l96pHuc7DsleQJUhB33?p=preview

Comment: You can use `element.children('[inner-directive]')`, no need to make it hard. *[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jCGONz7o6x3eUDGDI3Rn?p=preview)*

Comment: @Philipp Of course you can use children if you want it to work only with direct descendants. I gave generic solution.